# Rails forms - Should I build `accepts_nested_attributes_for` associations in the Controller, Model, or View?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

### The Question

I have a parent that `accepts_nested_attributes_for` a child. So, when I have a form for the parent, I need to `build` the child so I can display form fields for it as well. What I want to know is: where should I `build` the child? In the Model, View, or Controller?

### Why I Am Asking This

You may be shaking your head and thinking I'm a madman for asking a question like this, but here's the line of thinking that got me here.

I have a `Customer` model that `accepts_nested_attributes_for` a `billing_address`, like so:

```
class Customer
  belongs_to :billing_address, class_name: 'Address'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :billing_address
end
```

When I present a form for a new `Customer` to the user, I want to make sure there is a blank `billing_address`, so that the user actually sees fields for the `billing_address`. So I have something like this in my controller:

```
def new
  @customer = Customer.new
  @customer.build_billing_address
end
```

However, if the user doesn't fill out any of the `billing_address` fields, but tries to submit an invalid form, they will be presented with a form that no longer has fields for the `billing_address`, unless I put something like this in the `create` action of my controller:

```
def create
  @customer = Customer.new(params[:customer])
  @customer.build_billing_address if @customer.billing_address.nil?
end
```

There is another issue, which is that if a user tries to edit a `Customer`, but that `Customer` doesn't have an associated `billing_address` already, they won't see fields for the `billing_address`. So I have to add somethign like this to the controller:

```
def edit
  @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
  @customer.build_billing_address if @customer.billing_address.nil?
end
```

And something similar needs to happen in the controller's `update` method.

Anyway, this is highly repetitive, so I thought about doing something in the model. My initial thinking was to add a callback to the model's `after_initialize` event, like so:

```
class CustomerModel
  after_initialize :build_billing_address, if: 'billing_address.nil?'
end
```

But my spidey sense started tingling. Who's to say I won't instantiate a `Customer` in some other part of my code in the future and have this wreak havoc in some unexpected ways.

So my current thinking is that the best place to do this is in the form view itself, since what I'm trying to accomplish is to have a blank `billing_address` for the form and the form itself is the only place in the code where I know for sure that I'm about to show a form for the `billing_address`.

But, you know, I'm just some guy on the Internet. Where should I `build_billing_address`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though [this advice](http://www.sitepoint.com/complex-rails-forms-with-nested-attributes/) by Xavier Shay is from 2011, he suggests putting it in the ***view***, *"since this is a view problem (do we display fields or not?)"*:

**app/helpers/form_helper.rb:**

```
module FormHelper
  def setup_user(user)
    user.address ||= Address.new
    user
  end
end
```

**app/views/users/_form.html.erb:**

```
<%= form_for setup_user(@user) do |f| %>
```

Note that I had to change the helper method to the following:

```
  def setup_user(user)
    user.addresses.build if user.addresses.empty?
    user
  end
```

The *controller* remains completely unchanged.

Comment: I agree. This is the practice I have settled on over time and it seems to work well.

Answer (score 2):

If you know your model should *always* have a billing address, you can override the getter for this attribute in your model class as described in [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html):

```
def billing_address
    super || build_billing_address
end
```

Optionally pass in any attributes to `build_billing_address` as required by your particular needs.

Answer (score 1):

You would use build if you want to build up something and save it later. I would say, use it in nested routes.

```
def create
 @address = @customer.billing_addresses.build(params[:billing_address])
 if @address.save
   redirect_to @customer.billing_addresses
 else
   render "create"
 end
end
```

Something like that. I also use the build when I'm in the console.

Comment: I know when to use `build`, what I want to know is where is the best place to use it: the Model, the Controller, or the View.

Comment: You can build it in the controller OR you can, if every time you create a Customer and you want a billing address built, then you can just override the constructor if you want. Depends upon your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember the principles of [MVC](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#what-is-rails-questionmark), which is to create DRY(don't repeat yourself) code, which is efficiently distributed between the various moving parts of the app

**`accepts_nested_attributes_for` Is Great For Keeping Things DRY**

[`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) is a model function which allows you to pass data through an association to another model. The reason why it exists is to give you the ability to populate another model's data based on a single form, and is excellent for extending functionality without too much extra code

The problem you're citing is that if you want to use the code in other areas of the app, you'll end up having all sorts of problems

My rebuttal to that is in order to create as efficient an application as possible, **you want to write as little code as possible** - letting Rails handle everything. The `accepts_nested_attributes_for` function does allow you to do this, but obviously has a cost, in that you have to accommodate it every time you want to use it

My recommendation is to use what you feel is the most efficient code you can, but also keep to conventions; as this will ensure speed & efficiency

Comment: I am using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, so you're preaching to the choir there. But when I have a form for a parent which `accepts_nested_attributes_for` a child, I need to build the child in order to have an object for the child form. What I want to know is where is the best place to build the child: the Model, the Controller, or the View.

Comment: Okay, sorry about wrong answer. In keeping with Rails convention, I would try and keep the declarations in the controller, but it will probably be best to see some other answers to see more input :)

Answer (score 1):

You should handle all these scenarios in controller, since it is not a responsibility of model.

Just in terms of keeping things DRY, you can write a method,

```
def build_customer(customer)
  customer.build_billing_address if customer.billing_address.nil?
  #add more code if needed
end
```

And inside controller you can call this method wherever it is needed. e.g.

```
def create
  @customer = Customer.new(params[:customer])
  if @customer.save
    redirect_to @customer.billing_addresses
  else
    build_customer(@customer)
    render "new"
  end 
end
```